# Tabular splitting in cells with automatic split and words fitting

Tags: tables, line-breaking, loops

I need to create a 3 columns of the same width and split it into cells of the same hight, so when I print text and formulas it will automatically placed in the next cell if it doesn't fit. So when I print something in the bottom cell and it doesn't fit, it should be placed in next right up cell. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a (hand-drawn) sketch of what you're looking of achieve. Some more detailed examples of what the "cells" might be all about would also be welcome.

Comment: A separate thought:  Have you considered loading the [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package and typing `\begin{multicols}{3}` ... `\end{multicols}`?